# No matching constructor for initialization of - C++ & Objective C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to integrate Custom C++ class in an Objective C class this way:

C++ class header

```
class Analyzer
{

public:

    Analyzer(std::string const& face_cascade_url, std::string const&  eyes_cascade_url, std::string const&  nose_cascade_url );

};
```

Objective C header:

```
@interface cvVideoWrapper : UIViewController <CvVideoCameraDelegate>

@property Analyzer analyzer;

@end
```

Objective C implementation:

```
@implementation cvVideoWrapper


-(void) get_ready {

    NSString* face_filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2"
                               ofType:@"xml"];
    NSString* eyes_filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses"
                               ofType:@"xml"];
    NSString* nose_filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"haarcascade_mcs_nose"
                               ofType:@"xml"];

    self.analyzer = Analyzer([face_filename UTF8String], [eyes_filename UTF8String], [nose_filename UTF8String]);
}

@end
```

I'm getting at the Objective C implementation this error:

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'Analyzer'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use forward declaration here to sanitize your headers. And use the pointer instead of the instance.

Objective C header:

```
class Analyzer;

@interface cvVideoWrapper : UIViewController <CvVideoCameraDelegate>

@property Analyzer* analyzer;
//               ^^ it is a pointer now

@end
```

And then in Objective C implementation:

```
@implementation cvVideoWrapper

-(void) get_ready {

    NSString* face_filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2"
                               ofType:@"xml"];
    NSString* eyes_filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses"
                               ofType:@"xml"];
    NSString* nose_filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"haarcascade_mcs_nose"
                               ofType:@"xml"];

    // Create object here with new:
    self.analyzer = new Analyzer([face_filename UTF8String], [eyes_filename UTF8String], [nose_filename UTF8String]);
}

// Don't forget to cleanup when you're done:
- (void)dealloc
{
    delete self.analyzer;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you included Analyzer's header and have the Objective-C implementation compiling as Objective-C++, convert the value returned by `UTF8String` to a `std::string`. The compiler can't find a constructor that has the right signature nor for the automatically convertible values of the `UTF8String` return type.

`std::string([face_filename UTF8String])` et al should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to tie ObjC with C++, but it looks to me like the problem is that you're storing an `Analyzer` by value but it doesn't have a default constructor.  In C++ that would mean you'd need to provide the arguments for construction in the initializer list of the constructor for the containing class.  If that can't be done then you'd have to store by pointer.

It also looks like `Analyzer` doesn't have an assignment operator so that would be a problem too.